# Login loop after nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, ubuntu-drivers, nvidia-geforce, loop-device

I know this question has been asked before but i tried all of existing solutions non of them solutions worked for me.

Edit: My graphics card is 950M GEFORCE GTX

I've tried with Ubuntu 16.04 and ubuntu 14.04 in partition with windows 8.1. When i install the nvidia driver an reboot, i had a login loop.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If the guest login works, the problem is in your hidden "dot" files (those starting with a period).  Look for the solutions that rename or delete those files, starting with  .Xauthority .cache .local and .config.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making sure the driver I was installing was compatible with my kernel version. I am currently using kernel 4.14.18-300 and installed NVIDIA driver version 384.111 because it said it fixed issues similar to what you were having.

Comment: My kernel is 4.4.0-112-generic. What NVIDIA driver version i need?